# Embedded jetty server causing issues with UTF-8 characters

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

Code from servlet file

```java
 @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    try {
      Map map = req.getParameterMap();
      HashMap<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(map);
      String action = HTTPUtil.getInstance().getPropertyFromHttpRequest(PARAM_ACTION, paramsMap, false);
      String service = HTTPUtil.getInstance().getPropertyFromHttpRequest(PARAM_SERVICE_NAME, paramsMap, false);
     String requestBody = (String)IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream());

 ....
```

One of the field from requestBody is rendered as "Brad?" instead of "Brad's" in requestBody. Ideally "Brad's" should have been rendered. Which leads to incorrect data being stored in DB.

This is how jetty server is started :

```java
server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(10));
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(getPort());
server.addConnector(connector);
HandlerCollection handlerCollection = getHandlers();
server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
server.setStopTimeout(1000);
server.start();
```

getHandlers() return HandlerCollection is created as:

```java
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection(true);
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
handler.getContextPath();
handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new TestServlet(), "/test");
handlers.addHandler(handler);
```

Jetty Version 9.2.11.v20150529

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://master92.XYZ.com:7777/health?test=10&action=10' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{"name":"ABA …"}'
```

Request body shows up as

{"name": "ABA ?" } when dumped to logs or console

Comment: What version of Jetty?  What do your request headers look like?  What does the RAW / encoded form of the request look like before Jetty got a hold of it?  What is HTTPUtil doing?

Comment: Yes it was typo

Comment: Jetty Version 9.2.11.v20150529 POST request looks as following \r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 option.